# can't pass arguments to running flask webserver

Tags: python, flask

From my android app I make pictures with my raspberry pi via ssh and i try to upload them to a website with Flask. Before that the app ask the users to enter a code and I want this code to be in the url, this is why I need the `argparse`.

I want the server to be running and in the meantime I want to pass new urls to the script that creates pages. When I'm running `pitonka.py` and I add arguments, `tnb_flask.py` doesn't get them.

What can be the solution?

Thanks in advance!

pitonka.py:

```
   from flask import Flask
   import argparse
   import random


   tenor = ''
   def tuzok():
          if args.arg_name == "az":
          else:
                 tenor = ''
                 if args.arg_name == '':
                        tenor = ''
                 else:
                        tenor = args.arg_name
          print("tenor", tenor)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
          parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
          parser.add_argument("arg_name", help="Enter function's name", type=str, default ="az")
          args = parser.parse_args()
          tuzok()
```

tnb_flask.py

```
   from flask import Flask 
   from pitonka import *
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
          denis = 25
          print("tenor:+", tenor, "+")
          to_ret = "tenor:+" + tenor+  "+\n" + str(denis)
          return to_ret


   if __name__ == "__main__":
          app.run(debug=True)
          if tenor != "az":
                 print("nem az!!!")
                 @app.route('/tuna/<tenor>')
                 def index__(numbi):
                        return 'working: args.arg_name %s' % tenor
          else:
                 print("azzal egyezik meg")
```

Comment: *Before that the app ask the users to enter a code and I want this code to be in the url* - do you mean you want users to be able to create custom URLs for your Flask app?

Comment: yes, is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, you can use variables in Flask endpoints. It comes down to how end users will be entering these end points and how you want to map them in your code.

Comment: Adding arguments to the `index()` function is pointless, as you are just using the `tenor` variable which is already processed by your command line script. Is it the `denis` variable that you want to accept as argument instead of hard-coding it?

Comment: First I run tnb_flask.py, when it's running I run pitonka.py from another cmd and add a string as an argument after it like this: python pitonka.py dedo. I do not see why tenor won't be "dedo" and why I can't reach the page 127.0.0.1:5000/tuna/dedo. Thanks!

Comment: @birryree for experimental purposes I add arguments to the pitonka.py but before that I run tnb_flask.py which creates and runs the webserver. tnb_flask should get the argument passing from pitonka.py and creates there the urls. Could you tell me how I should modify my code to your endpoint solution? Thank you very much!